# Who do the top scores refer to?

Tags: unikong

The top scoring players in Unikong can be (scores omitted as they don't seem relevant):

> "JON", "RAR", "GBE", "KBR", "GBR", "JBU", "MCE", "JCH", "BCO", "OCO", "NCR", "GDA", "JDI", "BDU", "YEL", "AGA", "AGO", "MGR", "DHA", "JHA", "MHE", "BHO", "MHO", "NLA", "ALE", "TLI", "ALI", "SMA", "AMA", "MMC", "KMO", "BNI", "XNI", "CPE", "SPR", "JPU", "KRA", "DRO", "BRO", "JSH", "MSH", "KTH", "STR", "DWA", "AWA", "REX"

Inspecting the [source](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/unikong.js?v=e54129610ca2) of the game shows that "JON" is hard coded to be the top scorer and the remaining nine are randomly chosen from the list.

Are these "the trolls" mentioned in the ad?

[image]

Do these refer to community members or to Stack Exchange employees, and if not, what do they refer to?

I suspect JON refers to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), one of the makers as well as the top contributor of all-time on Stack Overflow, but what about the others? They don't seem to refer to the [other top contributors on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) or the [moderators on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). ALE may also refer to [Adam Lear](http://stackexchange.com/users/37099/adam-lear), one of the [SE employees](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) and developers of Unikong (mentioned in the credits).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're on the right track - they refer to a number of other developers and sysadmins who work at SE. In other words, yes, they are the trolls.

You can work out most of the names with [this handy guide](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team).

Answer (score 19):

Extending from [Adam Lear's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/261060/130645) answer

> they refer to a number of other developers and sysadmins who work at SE

With a the full list (from inspecting the code) provided by [@JohnB's edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/261044/3)

And sorting based on [information provided by @wythagoras' answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/261083/130645)

> the codes are sorted in alphabetic order on last name.

I present to you, [the trolls](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Engineering) (which fortunately appear sorted in the same way mentioned above):

- JON = Jon Skeet ([obviously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts))
- RAR = Roberta Arcoverde
- GBE = George Beech
- KBR = Kyle Brandt
- GBR = Greg Bray
- JBU = John Bubriski
- MCE = Marco Cecconi
- JCH = Jon Chan
- BCO = Bret Copeland
- OCO = Oded Coster (for some reason when I saw this, I immediately thought Oded)
- NCR = Nick Craver
- GDA = Geoff Dalgas
- JDI = Jarrod Dixon
- BDU = Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe
- YEL = Yaakov Ellis
- AGA = Aurelien Gasser
- AGO = Alec Gorge
- MGR = [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell), another of [SO's top contributors of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)
- DHA = David Haney
- JHA = Jason Harvey
- MHE = Mark Henderson
- BHO = Benjamin Hodgson
- MHO = Max Horstmann
- NLA = Nick Larsen
- ALE = Adam Lear
- TLI = Tom Limoncelli
- ALI = Arie Litovsky
- SMA = Shane Madden
- AMA = Adam Maras
- MMC = Mike McGranahan
- KMO = Kevin Montrose
- BNI = Brian Nickel
- XNI = Xavier Nicollet
- CPE = Graig Peterson
- SPR = Samo Prelog
- JPU = Jason Punyon
- KRA = Kasra Rahjerdi
- DRO = Dave Robinson
- BRO = Bryan Ross
- JSH = Jason Shantz
- MSH = Matt Sherman
- KTH = Kirti Thorat
- STR = Steve Trout
- DWA = Dean Ward
- AWA = Alex Warren
- REX = David Fullerton

Answer (score 4):

To be more precise, the codes seem to refer to the first letter of the first name and first two letters of the last name of the employees in the Engineering section of the link in Adam Lear's answer. Also, the codes are sorted in alphabetic order on last name.

The only one that doesn't fit is REX.